# Is txn.commit() required with Xodus?

Tags: java, xodus

Here's my code:

`@Override
    public void updateUser(String instance, String storeName, final String userId,
                           final String newUsername, final String newPassword) {
        if (storeName == null || storeName == null) {
            return;
        }
        final PersistentEntityStore entityStore = PersistentEntityStores.newInstance(xodusRoot + instance);
        entityStore.executeInTransaction(new StoreTransactionalExecutable() {
            @Override
            public void execute(@NotNull final StoreTransaction txn) {
                EntityId roleEntityId = txn.toEntityId(userId);
                final Entity entity = txn.getEntity(roleEntityId);
                if(newUsername != null) {
                    entity.setProperty("username", newUsername);
                }
                if(newPassword != null) {
                    entity.setProperty("password", newPassword);
                }
                //txn.commit();
            }
        });
        entityStore.close();
    }`

I want to know if for this code, is `txn.commit();` required so the transaction to be executed, how about for rollback?

ps.

I wanted this code to return boolean if all transaction completed successfully but cannot find way except for `txn.commit` which returns boolean, is that the way? So it must be required?

Answer (score 1):

If you use methods like `executeInTranction()` or `computeInTransaction()`, then you should not call `txn.commit()`. Just use the `executeInTranction()` method to make sure the transaction is committed - if your program reached the next statement after executeInTranction then the transaction was committed.

Comment: Ok I see, so plainly setting the response to true at the end of the line of the execute will mean that transaction completed? Nice.

Comment: @xybrek you can use `computeInTransaction()` that returns `true` as a final statement, but it's the same as just use executeInTransaction and don't check the return value.